# Trying to use Google Calendar V3 With Python/Django I got this error: 'str' object has no attribute 'calendars'

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to connect my django app with the Google Calendar API v3.

To do this I'm using the [Google API Python client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/)

In the docs I see a reference about how to create a [service object](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started#build).

I see an example of how to use it here [Django example from Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg/samples/django_sample). 
This is a portion of my views.

```
import logging
import httplib2
from oauth2client.django_orm import Storage
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.util import logger
from apiclient.discovery import build
from core.models import FlowModel, CredentialsModel
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect 
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext

FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id= _cliente_id,
        client_secret= _cliente_secret,
        scope= _scope,
        user_agent=_user_agent)

current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
URI = "http://"+str(current_site)+"/auth_return"

def authentice(request):
    user = request.user
    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
    credential = storage.get()
    if credential is None or credential.invalid == True:

        authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url(URI)
        f = FlowModel(id=user, flow=flow)
        f.save()
        return authorize_url
    else:
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credential.authorize(http)

        # The Service Object

        service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http)

        return service


def auth_return(request):
    f = FlowModel.objects.get(id=request.user)

    credential = f.FLOW.step2_exchange(request.REQUEST) #Zica aqui...

    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
    storage.put(credential)
    f.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")


def new_calendar(request):
    service = authentice(request)

    if request.POST:

        service = authentice(request)    

        calendar = {
            'summary': request.POST.get("summary"),
            'timeZone': 'America/Santo_Domingo'
        }

        created_calendar = service.calendars().insert(body=calendar).execute()


        return HttpResponseRedirect("/") 
    else:
        return render_to_response('calendar_form.html',
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is returning the next error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'calendars'

It's actually returning an string (A URL) an not a Service Object, and I don't know why.

If one of you have any idea, please help me with this.

PS: Sorry for my English! :P

Comment: Is authentice(request) returning a string when it shouldn't?

Comment: You return a url (a string) if the user isn't authenticated.

Comment: Yes, it has to return a service object.